# How to move using angles

Tags: java

I was wondering of how you would move something on a JFrame using angles such as

```
player.move(23);
```

would move the player at an angle of 23. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!!

Comment: Trignometry. Look it up, or take an entry high-school level math course.

Comment: I'm in middle school.

Comment: Then look it up. I'll answer this anyway...

Comment: Why not just explain it to me?

Comment: Math questions are likely better asked on Math.SE: [trigonometry tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) - that said, make sure you look it up first.  "Explain trigonometry to me" would be too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `speed` is the speed to move at and `angle` is the angle in degrees to move in:

```
x += speed*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
y += speed*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

Comment: k I'm in high school now; I listened to your request. XD

Comment: @Game Master Jack ;) (oh god I was a dick when I first answered this question I apologize)

Comment: it's ok it was a incredibly stupid question; plus welcome to the internet land of dicks :D

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/transformations/. I think it's what you need:

[image]